# ¿Cómo puedo sumar valores dentro de una lista con valores tipo int y float?

Tags: python-3.x

Tengo números en una lista de forma que:

```
lista=[8.0,9.0,135.6,156.4]
```

Quisiera poder sumarlos con la función `sum()`, pero al poner `sum(lista)` me da un error que dice

> "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str' "

Cabe destacar que esa lista fue generada luego de un *append** y ademas no se que tipo son los elementos dentro de la lista (int o str o float)  y la verdad no se como poder seguir.

mis pregunta es, ¿como puedo eliminar los números que vienen luego del punto (y el punto obviamente)(105.xxxx)y convertir a entero para poder sumarlos con el comando?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

prueba viendo el tipo de dato que tienes en la lista

```
for num in lista:
    print(type(num))
```

si son string haces la conversión a float(num)

Comment: Gracias la verdad era bastante obvio pero no lo pensé :( se agradece

Comment: @antoniooo0 como eres nuevo probablemente no lo sepas, pero la mejor forma de dar las gracias en StackOverflow es marcar la respuesta como correcta y por que no, darle también un voto positivo.